# Firefox 4 Status Bar UI Element "Waiting for domain.com..." -- How do I pin this down to a specific location?

Tags: firefox

In Firefox 4, the "Waiting for domain..." status bar (UI Element) appears in one of two spots.

[image]

I would like to pin it to a specific spot.

Is this possible?

Update: not a debugging question. Just a UI Tweak.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Install [status-4 ever.](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/status-4-evar/)  This reverts back to the old ways.

Comment: But this doesn't provide extra information in comparison to that seen in the screenshot?

Answer (score 1):

[image]

1. Install [**Firebug**](http://getfirebug.com/), open it by pressing <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>F12</kbd> or by clicking the Firebug icon.
2. Go to the **Net** tab and **Enable** it.
3. Now, **refresh** your page and you should be able to see what request is failing...
4. Do not forget to **Disable** the net tab when you are done.

You can also use this in the future to troubleshoot a lot of other web related problems.

For example, I have `edge.quantserve.com` blocked in my `hosts` file which shows up above.

Comment: A valuable hint for debugging, but not answering the question

Comment: @Mateng: The question originally asked to obtain location, this does and therefore it answers the original question; even with the edited form of the question, it helps to get rid of the status bar.